# hiding an element in html dynamically which is in anchor tag

Tags: html, angular, mean-stack

How to hide an element which is inside anchor tag in navigation bar? I've already tried `ng-hide` but its not working.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse text-" style="height: 60px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <img src="\assets\nextel.png">

                <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" [nghide]="x" [routerLink]="['login']" style=" margin-top: 32px;
                color: #000;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

here i mentioned `[nghide]="x"` where x is true it has to appear otherwise it has to disappear the element whatever i mentioned in anchor tag.
but whenever i tried this the total nav bar is disappearing.what is the solution.

Comment: If you are using AngularJS on this project, edit the question and add it to question tags to receive more help from others.

Comment: can you edit the question to make it better in understanding?

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

try `ng-hide="x"` instead of `[nghide]="x"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular not AngularJS. If I am correct, you need to use `*ngIf` like

```
<a class="navbar-brand pull-right" *ngIf="x" [routerLink]="['login']" style=" margin-top: 32px;color: #000;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a>
```

Comment: Thank you its working.But whenever i come back to same page it has to appear but it is in disappearing mode only

Comment: @i.s.nraju how you are setting `x` value? You should set it in `ngOnInit()` block for initial page load.

Comment: i took separate method which is called when click event occured

Comment: what is the use of ngOnit() , can u explain me?